# WordPress Page Slug with URL custom template

Tags: page-template, slug

So I want to create a custom template file for my user profile page something like this URL http://localhost/wordpress/user/username.

Here you can see I have created a new page in Admin with this permalink `user` and I have created a new file in my theme directory at `theme/user/page-{slug}.php`  and below is my code for this file.

```
<?php 

/*
    Template Name: User Profile
*/
wp_head();

?>

This is user profile page
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

I have also selected this template file in admin for this page and below is the screenshot of this newly created page.

[image]

But when I go to browser and try this URL http://localhost/wordpress/user/company , its giving me "Page Not Found" error.

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here ? How can I set a template based on this slug `company` here which has `user` in the URL.

Comment: Does a post with the slug `company` exist in the WordPress posts table, or is `company` a child of the `user` page? What is "username" - the username of a registered user on your site, or is it just a custom parameter used in your page template? Also, I know `/user/username` displays a user profile page, but what would `/user/` display?

Comment: @SallyCJ its actually a `page` and `company` is just a slug and it wont be in posts table or in any table. Its just a custom parameter. `/user/` without slug I will check and redirect if without slug.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply, but I'm glad you already found a solution. All the best.

Comment: No worries dear .. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out a solution. Below is how I have achieved this.

In my `functions.php` file, I have put below code.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_user_var', 0, 1);
function add_user_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'user';
    return $vars;
}

add_rewrite_rule('^user/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?pagename=user&user=$matches[1]','top');
```

This generally adds a rewrite rule if it finds `user` in the URL.

Now I have added a page template file name called as `page-user.php` and added below code to grab my query string.

```
$user = get_query_var('user');
echo $user;
```

I have created a page in backend admin with slug `user` and selected this template for this page.

Hope this helps.